# Wix bootstrapper How to prevent rollback

Tags: c#, wix, windows-installer, bootstrapper, burn

I would like to know if there is a way to prevent rollback when a Package fail.

Like in my case I have a .bat package that sets the user name and password for some services. And if it fails, I want to show a message at the end of the installation telling that the user need to set the credential manually. Also when I check the credential before the installation, and for some reason they failed I tell the user that the credential could be wrong and ask him if he wants to continue.

(Else I wouldn't want to prevent the rollback)

I know there is the `<ExitCode/>` in `<ExePackage/>` that I can use to prevent the rollback, but then I can't detect the error value in my Bootstrapper.

I also tried to read the Status in my Bootstrapper when the package complete and then return one of the following:

```
e.Result = Result.Continue;
e.Result = Result.Ignore;
e.Result = Result.Ok;
```

Exemple of reading the Status:

```
if (e.Status == -2147024895)
{
    e.Result = Result.Continue;
}
```

But it still rollsback.

Comment: In your package definitions you can use `<ExitCode>` to tell it to just continue on specific errors, just be careful which ones you let through since they may be errors from other types of actions.

Comment: @BrianSutherland Like said in question: I know there is the `<ExitCode/>` in `<ExePackage/>` that I can use to prevent the rollback, but then I can't detect the error value in my Bootstrapper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my answer from here: http://lists.wixtoolset.org/pipermail/wix-users-wixtoolset.org/

Basically, all you need to do is set the package you want to handle the return code to `Vital='no'` and in the `ExecutePackageComplete` handler use `e.Result = Result.Ignore;` to prevent rollback.